# Class based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I'd like to disable on any handheld devices (tablets, phones). I've got it set up for anything greater than 1200px but wondering if this is the best way to go about it....wondering if I should be targeting the mobile devices rather than the larger screens or...?

I know there are several similar questions out there and I've been reading them for hours but want advice on my specific code.

Note, I am using Media Queries but they will not work here.

Thanks very much in advance,
Susan

```
ShowImageZoomer = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
var current_width = $(window).width();    
    if(current_width > 1200)
    $(".QuickView").quickview({
        buttonText: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewButtonText%%",
        buttonColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewButtonColor%%",
        gradientColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewGradientColor%%",
        textColor: "%%GLOBAL_QuickViewTextColor%%"
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you disabling it based on size or because these are touch devices?  I ask because sometimes it's better to test for capabilities rather than making assumptions about devices based on screen size.  If it's based on size and not capabilities, you'll want to add a resize listener in case the user resizes the window after document ready has dispatched.

Comment: You should get familiar with [MediaQueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: if a tablet has 1280px width then this would fire as well. I think the android tablets are 1280. Detecting based on size is more reliable as long as your site is build for it. Now days a lot of table top tablets are touch screen but it's not a handheld device. Depending on what devices you need to disable this, might be worth it to detect user agent + size for a more accurate reading

Comment: hi. NaNpx: resize listener as in $(window).resize(function(){ or...?  Teemu: I am familiar with MediaQueries and have a stylesheet dedictated for that purpose. However, it won't work here. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. Huangism: So you're saying I should not use the above script or just change the size or keep as is and detect user agent? I know user agent detection is useful but have read many comments against relying on it so wanted to cover the screen size. However, I am primarily interested in disabling this feature on touch screen devices. Thanks!